# How to remember a proof for a long time

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

A very basic question of mine:

Whenever I read a proof I am able to remember it only for a couple of months.
But I really want to remember it for at least one year or so if not more.

Is it the natural way or is it that once you read a proof of a theorem you are able to recollect it even after a few years

I am feeling quite frustrated in this regard because for an interview in Mathematics the interview committee asks all the basic proofs involved in solving any given problem

What should I do?

I know that there are many Mathematicians here who are able to share some thoughts on this topic

Comment: The best way to remember the proof of a theorem is to actually prove it yourself without looking at a proof devised by someone else. This will force you to remember it because *you* are the one who proved it.

Comment: Two months sound good to me! What one should be able to do for a much longer time is to *reconstruct* a proof.  But that may not be a quick process, and is difficult to do under interview (or exam) conditions.